# How to get the position of a slider in a Plotly chart in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, slider, plotly

I am making a chart in python using the plotly library. The chart has a slider and i would like to retrieve the position of the slider in order to use it to display something else (cannot be done in plotly). Is there a way to have plotly return the position of the slider?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

- you can get the slider value using a **callback** in **dash**
- have used https://plotly.com/python/sliders/#sliders-in-plotly-express as sample for plot with a slider
- cannot do a direct callback, hence use of an **Interval** passing in the state as well
- updates a **div** with active step and active value

```
import plotly.express as px
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

df = px.data.gapminder()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])

fig["layout"].pop("updatemenus") # optional, drop animation buttons

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [dcc.Graph(id="graph", figure=fig), 
     dcc.Interval(id="sliderInterval", interval=400, n_intervals=0),
     html.Div(id="whichframe", children=[]),
    ],
)

# core update of figure on change of dash slider    
@app.callback(
    Output("whichframe", "children"),
    Input("sliderInterval", "n_intervals"),
    State("graph", "figure")
)
def setFrame(n_intervals, fig):
    slider = fig['layout']['sliders'][0]
    return f"active:{slider['active']} value:{slider['steps'][slider['active']]['args'][0][0]}"

# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode="inline")
```